# list attribute has no order by

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I tried to do a sorting in sqlalchemy query, the parameters come from 'query_sort' which contains a list of sort parameter (field and direction).

here is the code

```
      def select_all(self, query_paging, query_sort):
          """ method to select all the transport type"""
          try:
              select_all_query =\
              self._session.query(TransportType)
              for s in query_sort:
                  select_all_query =\
>>                select_all_query.order_by(s.dir(getattr(TransportType,  s.field)))\
                  .limit(query_paging.page_size)\
                  .offset(query_paging.skip)\
                  .all()
              return select_all_query
          except NoResultFound:
              return None
```

Then in py.test, I tried to test this program by using this code :

```
s1 = sort
s1.field = "type"
s1.dir = asc

s2 = sort
s2.field = "transport_type_id"
s2.dir = asc

query_sort = [s1,s2]

query_paging.skip = 1
query_paging.page_size = 10
transport_types = repo.select_all(query_paging, query_sort)
assert len(transport_types) == 1
```

when I ran the test, I got this error :

```
E               AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'order_by'
```

It worked fine when I was only using one data (s1) but when I try to test it using more than one data then it produces this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You called `.all()` on your query, which returns all results of the query in a list:

```
select_all_query =\
select_all_query.order_by(s.dir(getattr(TransportType,  s.field)))\
.limit(query_paging.page_size)\
.offset(query_paging.skip)\
.all()
```

so the *next* iteration of the loop `select_all_query` is now a list.

If you need to apply different orderings, do *just that* in the loop:

```
select_all_query = self._session.query(TransportType)
for s in query_sort:
    select_all_query = select_all_query.order_by(
        s.dir(getattr(TransportType,  s.field)))

select_all_query = (
    select_all_query.limit(query_paging.page_size)
                    .offset(query_paging.skip)
                    .all())
return select_all_query
```

Answer (score 5):

My solution was to change the `all().order_by()` to `filter().order_by()`

To order post by recent date posted I did.

`posts = Post.query.filter().order_by('date_posted desc')`

Hope that helps.